# HCE and different OS versions

Tags: android

I have downloaded the two Google examples concerning HCE (the CardEmulator and the CardReader) and run them on two different devices:

- a Nexus 9 running Android 5
- a LG G2, running Android 4.4

According to the documentation, both the apps should work on both the devices, but no data are exchanged when:

- G2 behaves as the reader, and Nexus 9 as the card.

The two Google apps only work when the Nexus 9 is the reader and G2 is the card.

I have no error messages, no strange log messages. Is there anyone who can point me to the right direction for understanding why they don't work?

I am building the apps with Android Studio 1.1, with API Level 22 or 21 and target/min platform: API Level 19.